# CKEditor - How to remove a specific attribute?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Any ideas on how to remove / disallow a specific attribute with CKEditor?

So in my case I am trying to remove / disable all "style" attributes (inline css) from all HTML elements.

I was reading and this is suggested to do the job, although nothing happens:

```
config.disallowedContent = 'style';
```

This was another method found online, doesn't work either:

```
config.disallowedContent = 'div[style*]; p[style]; h1[style]; h2[style]'; // etc etc
```

Another suggestion, which didn't work!

```
config.disallowedContent = '{style}';
```

More "suggestions" are welcome! Cmon let's figure this one :)

EDIT: I've setup a clean install of "Full Package" for testing purposes!

Comment: try `config.disallowedContent = 'style; *[style*]';`

Comment: @TamilSelvan Doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Could you please check if any error in console

Comment: @TamilSelvan Nope, no errors in console.

Comment: try `CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = {
    $1: {
        // Use the ability to specify elements as an object.
        elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
        attributes: true,
        styles: false,
        classes: true
    }
};
CKEDITOR.config.disallowedContent = '*[style*]';`

Comment: @TamilSelvan Actually, I don't believe you need the `CKEDITOR.config.disallowedContent = '*[style*]';` part of it. It should work with just setting styles to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to allow content using object format. Because simply declaring [config.allowedContent](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content) to be equal true will turn off [Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) at all. Official CK Editor example of allowing all tags with object format:

```
config.allowedContent = {
  $1: {
        elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
        attributes: true,
        styles: true,
        classes: true
      }
  };
```

The second thing is you *cannot* filter style attribute, well, as an attribute. CKEditor works with pattern elements[attributes]{styles}(classes). Style element specifically works with pattern in curly braces.
`*[*]{height}` will match all elements with for example `style="height:10px"`. To deny style attribute completely everywhere you can use this pattern:

```
*[style]{*}
```